# no implicit conversion of Hash into String when using fastlane

Tags: ruby, fastlane

when I am using this command in macOS Catalina 10.15:

```
bundle exec fastlane beta
```

shows this error:

```
[00:04:45]: To not be asked about this value, you can specify it using 'git_url'
+------------------+----------+
|        Lane Context         |
+------------------+----------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM | ios      |
| PLATFORM_NAME    | ios      |
| LANE_NAME        | ios beta |
+------------------+----------+
[00:04:45]: no implicit conversion of Hash into String

+------+------------------+-------------+
|           fastlane summary            |
+------+------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action           | Time (in s) |
+------+------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform | 0           |
| 2    | is_ci            | 0           |
| 3    | is_ci            | 0           |
|    | match            | 0           |
+------+------------------+-------------+

[00:04:45]: fastlane finished with errors

Looking for related GitHub issues on fastlane/fastlane...

Could not access the GitHub API, you may have better luck via the website.
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/search?q=no implicit conversion of Hash into String&type=Issues&utf8=✓
bundler: failed to load command: fastlane (/Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/bin/fastlane)
/Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/highline-1.7.10/lib/highline.rb:624:in `encode': \e[31m[!] no implicit conversion of Hash into String\e[0m (TypeError)
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/highline-1.7.10/lib/highline.rb:624:in `say'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/highline-1.7.10/lib/highline.rb:261:in `ask'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/forwardable.rb:238:in `ask'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/implementations/shell.rb:130:in `input'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/ui.rb:17:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/configuration/configuration.rb:243:in `fetch'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/match/lib/match/runner.rb:34:in `run'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/sync_code_signing.rb:14:in `run'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:263:in `block (2 levels) in execute_action'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/actions_helper.rb:69:in `execute_action'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:255:in `block in execute_action'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:229:in `chdir'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:229:in `execute_action'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:157:in `trigger_action_by_name'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:159:in `method_missing'
    from Fastfile:22:in `block (2 levels) in parsing_binding'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:33:in `call'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:49:in `block in execute'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `chdir'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `execute'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane_manager.rb:47:in `cruise_lane'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb:36:in `handle'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:178:in `call'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:153:in `run'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:476:in `run_active_command'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:76:in `run!'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/delegates.rb:15:in `run!'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:352:in `run'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:41:in `start'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:122:in `take_off'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/bin/fastlane:23:in `load'
    from /Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli.rb:497:in `exec'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/exe/bundle:49:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:130:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.2.3/exe/bundle:37:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
```

what should I do to fix it? This is my fastlane version info:

```
~/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios on  main! ⌚ 0:04:51
$ fastlane -v
fastlane installation at path:
/usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.177.0/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.177.0/bin/fastlane
-----------------------------
[✔] 
/usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.177.0/libexec/gems/highline-1.7.10/lib/highline.rb:624: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated
fastlane 2.177.0
(base)
```

Comment: If it's an issue with their gem and not your code, I would go over to their Github and look at the issues - see if anyone else reported the same thing, and if not, make your own bug report